# Browser goes Back after PHP page is executed

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a form which sends data to a proccess page. Is it possible when the code in the process page is executed for the browser to jump back to the previous page?

**EDIT**

The reason i want this, is because i have a set of parameters which contains checkboxes. These parameters are echoed out via a while loop. I have a table where it shows which of those parameters are active. I would like to check the checkboxes by defualt where the corresponding parameter is in the table.

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| Example ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

PARAMETERS:

T-Shirt:            checked
Distance:        checked
 
Race:                 unchecked

TABLE (parameters)
• T-Shirt
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
the example above checks the box if it already exists in the parameters table. When the user clicks back after the process page, the boxes he selected is checked.

Hope i am clear enough

Regards

Comment: Why can't you use redirect with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` for example?

Comment: Because if the user clicks back. The previous page's form data is still filled.

Comment: @user973254: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not reliable. The user-agent might not pass it.

Comment: You can easily fill it with user entered data after redirect. btw you can use `<script type="text/javascript">window.location(history.back);</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a nice solution might be to implement a front controller for your webbage, a central script to include the appropirate page. Using a system like that, the user stays on the same page all the time even when other pages are loaded.

I haven't used a front controller in quite some time, so I won't write examples due to potential errors and poor coding. You can probably find some examples using google though, I wouldn't be surprised if the subject has been brought up here on Stackoverflow before either.

Comment: That's quite silly approach. If user always stays on the same page, how do the front controller know, what page to show?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel By page, I mean script. As the OP specified it to be a "processing page", I can only imagine it isn't something a user should see but rather go silently in the background. It would also remove the need of going back in history when the script is done.

Comment: weak excuse. the OP has a sensible design and you don't. "staying on the same page all the time even when other pages are loaded" IS NOT an option.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel When other, specified, pages are loaded. That doesn't mean every page should be loaded using the front controller, only suitable pages like the one OP is describing.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel To answer your first comment, as I see you've edited, the front controller is in index.php. As it doesn't seem like you know what a front controller is, you can find a description [here](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_front_controller_and_php). If you read you notice that you can easily access other pages while using index.php by passing GET or POST data to the front controller.

Comment: LOL, all that stuff doesnt make your answer sensible.

Comment: I'll have to argue that this is the *only* sensible solution for setting up any sort of webapp. Never rely on Javascript to do the redirection for you, simply re-load the form and fill in any values you want in the input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'll have to point out Griffin's solution is the best, if you're dead set on a redirect, simply have your PHP script execute the following lines:

```
echo '<script>document.history.go(-1);</script>';
die();
```

Or even

```
die('<script>document.history.go(-1);</script>');
```

It's a dirty solution, so I must advise against it.